# How to run jigdo on Windows 10

Tags: debian, windows-10

I am used to using [Jigdo](http://atterer.org/jigdo) to compile Debian CD/DVD images. Since moving from WIndows 7 to Windows 10, I get the following message when I try to run jigdo-lite.bat:

```
Jigsaw Download "lite"
Copyright (C) 2001-2005  |  jigdo@
Richard Atterer          |  atterer.net
      0 [main] sh 2712 sync_with_child: child 10236(0x170) died before initialization with status code 0xC0000142
   1197 [main] sh 2712 sync_with_child: *** child state waiting for longjmp
jigdo-lite: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I managed to find [this comment](http://atterer.org/jigdo/debian-jigdo-mini-howto#comment-3983) from someone having the same problem with Windows 8. The link given in the solution is out of date, though. I have also tried updating my msys-1.0.dll file by installing MSYS-1.0.11.exe and copying the DLL into jigdo-bin. The error goes away, but jigdo still refuses to run.

Has anybody managed to get jigdo working on Windows 10?

Comment: I currently have Windows 10 installed, and decided to also installed the ubuntu sub system.
I got the windows jigdo-lite.bat to run by editing the bat file, changing sh to bash and then running it as admin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get `jigdo-lite` running using Cygwin (32bit https://cygwin.com/install.html). Important to mention: the binary in `jigdo-bin\jigdo-lite` directory, NOT jigdo-lite.bat.

```
Successfully created `debian-8.5.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso'
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Finished!
The fact that you got this far is a strong indication that `debian-8.5.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso'
was generated correctly. I will perform an additional, final check,
which you can interrupt safely with Ctrl-C if you do not want to wait.

OK: Checksums match, image is good!
```

I also tried the built in Ubuntu-Bash in Windows 10 Aniverary Version 1607 (http://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/). But there was a `template checksum mismatch` when running jigdo-lite.

Answer (score 2):

Previous answer's excellent.
But you can fix the error by doing in W10 bash (not CMD) :

```
    apt-get -y install jigdo-file
```

Comment: I request you to please add some context/commentary around the code/idea/suggestion you have shared. It will help the asker and other future readers to understand your post better.

Comment: Would like to know exactly how to execute your example, but you did not leave any example code only an apt-get which is ONLY executable from Debian or Ubuntu, not a Powershell or a CMD shell (not even in admin mode)

Answer (score 2):

To clarify [Martin Seitl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38906867/276648) and [Dantes Haaketsu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41667567/276648) answers, after [RBT's request for additional information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36117167/how-to-run-jigdo-on-windows-10#comment70533450_41667567):

On Windows 10 you can use *Bash on Ubuntu on Windows* (check the [official page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install_guide) for prerequisites and installation procedure). This allows you to **run Linux command on your Windows system**.

Within Bash you can simply run jigdo, as if you were on Linux:

1. install it by doing `apt-get -y install jigdo-file`
2. run it by doing `jigdo-lite`

I was getting the same error as [iaina](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36117167/276648) with jigdo-lite.bat. The jigdo-lite on Bash seems to be working nicely (I just tried with a debian image and it worked).

Answer (score 1):

Visit this link:

http://atterer.org/jigdo/debian-jigdo-mini-howto

The solution in section: "Win8.1 64bit failure":

Download msys-1.0.dll from https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MSYS/Base//msys-core/
, extract it and then replace  the "msys-1.0.dll" into "jigdo-bin" folder overwriting the original.

This solution has fixed the error on my windows 10.

Comment: Welcome to SO! While the contents of the link you provided might answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer in your post and provide the link for reference, since link only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.